# ADFS Relying Party trust which has a querystring parameter

Tags: adfs

Is there a way to navigate the user to a Relying Party, which has a querystring parameter?

**BackGround**

We are using ADFS 2.0 wherein we have setup the Relying Party trust with Claim Rules for Single Sign On (SSO) of a vendor application. We are doing this using IdpInitiatedSignOn and SAML 2.0. So, we are able to navigate the user to a SSO like *mycompany.com*; however we are not able to figure out, how to navigate the user to a different page of same application which has a query string parameter e.g. *mycompany.com?index = 123*

We tried to use RelayState to resolve this, but no luck. This is my first post. My apologies if I have missed on giving enough information.

Comment: Have you installed Rollup 2? Encode the RelayState correctly? http://blog.auth360.net/2012/12/16/saml-2-0-idp-initiated-sign-on-with-relaystate-in-adfs-2-0/

Comment: Rollup 3 is installed, which is a cumulative package of Rollup 1 and 2. To encode the relaystate, we used ADFS relaystate generator but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do a direct SSO with a deep link. There are several walkthroughs, but they aren't terrible clear about what you need. As I used them for this answer, I will share them.

**TLDR answer:**

```
**[ADFS base URL]**/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx?RelayState=EncodedURL(RPID=EncodedURL(**[LoginToRP value]***)&RelayState=EncodedURL(**[Destination URL]**))

Target: mydestinationURL
LoginRPID: myLoginRPIDValue
Base ADFS URL: https://adfs.myDomain.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx

Example: https://adfs.myDomain.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx?RelayState=RPID%3DmyLoginRPIDValue%26RelayState%3DmydestinationURL
```

**References:**

> website to break down proper SAML and direct one way auth: http://www.confusedamused.com/notebook/adfs-relaystate
>
> website to help generate/validate proper URL: https://jackstromberg.com/adfs-relay-state-generator/
>
> website for HTML encoding values: https://www.url-encode-decode.com/

**Logic breakdown:**

1A) HTML Encode the target URL

1B) HTML Encode the LoginToRP parameter

2) Concatenate them together in this format: RPID=[HTML Encoded LoginToRP value]&RelayState=[HTML Encoded Target URL]

3) HTML Encode concatenated String

4) Concatenate Base URL and encoded string: [base URL]?RelayState=[double encoded string]

5) Result:

https://adfs.myDomain.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx?RelayState=RPID%3DmyLoginRPIDValue%26RelayState%3DmydestinationURL